# Laravel Localization prefix - URl "/" not working without locale

Tags: laravel, localization

I've did whats written in [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website/replies/78402) in order to add Localization prefixes to my URLs. However when I visit "/" there is an error: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`.

This is my Routesfile `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'MainController@showMainPage', 'as' => 'showMainPage']);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'backend'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'UserController@agentLogin', 'as' => 'agentLogin']);
});
```

Function:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function showMainPage()
    {
        return redirect()->route('/fr');
    }
}
```

`localhost:8000/fr` and `localhost:8000/en` are working fine.

How can I redirect `/` to the fallback locale (`/fr`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try make lang param optional:

```
'prefix' => '{lang?}'
```

Comment: Yes, this redirects me to /fr, however the page aborts due to too many redirections. I know why, but not how I could solve this

Comment: @Scarwolf and what about url `localhost:8000/fr`? Is it works correct? Only `localhost:8000` lead to too many redirections?

Comment: Woops, had to exchange the redirect to `route()`. Now it works fine, thanks!

Comment: My route links are shown with `/en` in the urls when on `localhost:8000` without `/fr`, even though I set the fallback locale to fr. Do you kniw why? Linking on my route like this: `{{ route('agentLogin') }}`. Route in `web.php`: ` Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'UserController@agentLogin', 'as' => 'agentLogin']);` Even when on a page with `/fr` it shows `/en` on links. Worked before making the lang-variable optional

Comment: Are you decide this trouble? What `'locale' =>` param you have in `app.php`?